# when a keyboard key(any) is pressed globally a function needs to be called. im using user32.dll hooks

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private IntPtr KeyboardHookDelegate(Int32 Code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (Code < 0)
    {
        return Process.WindowsHooksHelper.CallNextHookEx(
            keyBoardHandle, Code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    if (KeyBoardKeyPressed != null)
    {
        KeyBoardKeyPressed(this, new EventArgs());

    }

    return Process.WindowsHooksHelper.CallNextHookEx(
        keyBoardHandle, Code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When a key is pressed **globally** a function has to be called **KeyPressed()**. I'm using user32.dll hooks. Its working but its working only for 3 to 4 times, but not working after several times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your Process.WindowsHooksHelper class,

but I think there is a mistake in cleaning up something.

The cleanest solution that I know so far to listen to keys globally is this one:

https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698